# Hosting a web application in Asp.net Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core

I am trying to implement an application in Asp.net Core MVC. And I want to host my application for free to test and show. So, I would like to know what platform to choose and what steps to take. (knowing that this is the first time I host a website).

thank you in advance

Comment: You could host in Windows, Linux and MacOs, check [Host and deploy ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/?view=aspnetcore-2.2) for available hosting options.

Comment: You can check hosting recommendation here https://windowswebhostingreview.com/looking-for-asp-net-core-2-hosting-try-this-provider/